# How come Chrome opens some PDFs directly while DL others?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-reader

It would be nice to just view the pdf within chrome without saving it in the download folder (in Mac, I don't know how it is in other OS'). After a while you get tones of material in your download folder and you don't know which one is really worth keeping.

So how come some PDF's are open as a new tab while others download automatically to the mentioned folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is pretty simple. The server actually makes the decision to either download, or render the PDF in the browser. So the server admin must set the server to do either option, or the web developer / webmaster can add code to force the PDF either way.

On your end, you can run a plugin called [redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh), that changes the http-header that tells the browser to download the PDF, and actually make it do the opposite.

You create a rule that removes the  `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: So I guess it costs more for the server if they choose the non-downloading option?

Comment: No, either way, the PDF is being downloaded. It is just what happens to it when it gets to the browser that changes. BTW, updated the answer to give you a way to force the change on your side.

Comment: So the PDF is being downloaded anyway, but not to the download folder in both cases?

Comment: Exactly. If you think of the PDF as an object, that object has to make its way onto your computer in order for you to see it. It just downloads to a temporary, or cached file, in order for it to be displayed in your browser or Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. And that's how I like it (the temp. cached way). If I want to download it then I specifically tell the computer to do so. So you say the redirector exactly does this? Does it make the browser slower? Have you notice any negatives with redirector? Thanks for all your input bro.

Comment: No, what it does is fool the browser into thinking that the server said for it to be displayed in the browser's PDF viewer. Google HTTP headers and you'll be able to learn more than I can explain in the comments here. It's changing the HTTP header upon arrival from the server.